# `onCopyCommand` on macOS is never being called. How to use it?

Tags: macos, swiftui

Does anyone know how to use `onCopyCommand` / `onPasteCommand` modifier in SwiftUI on macOS?
I can't make it being called.

No matter where I put it, 'copy / cut / paste` menu items are disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are using a custom view, you need to make sure it is focused.
Currently, the only way I know to focus a view (in SwiftUI) is with the `focusable` modifier

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyView {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("can be focused by pressing 'TAB'")
        }
        .focusable()
        .onCopyCommand {
            return [NSItemProvider(/* some data */)]
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**
The only way to focus a custom View with `focusable()` modifier, is with the **TAB** key. I guess that mouse clicks are not yet supported.

I have got more Info [Here](https://swiftui-lab.com/working-with-focus-on-swiftui-views/)

Comment: Oh damn, that's a pitty. It's only useful for pretty straightforward cases then. I hope they'll improve this API in future releases.

Anyway, Thanks for help Gal!

Comment: You are absolutely right, but I'm optimistic it will get better in time. If that helped you I'd would appreciate to mark as 'answer' ;)

Comment: In order to be able to use the TAB button, turn on the Keyboard Navigation in System Settings. When it's working- the focused Text has a blue border.